# Select last two columns in R and form a new column by dividng the last two columns without using index

Tags: r

The data is

```
m2 <- data.frame(a = c(1:5),b = c(1:5),"2016"= c(1:5),"2017"= c(1:5),"2018"= c(1:5),"2019" = c(1:5))
```

This needs to be down without the use of indexes

```
m2$new_col <- m2[,5]/m2[,6]
```

The actual number of columns in unknown. However, we always have two divide the last two only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ncol`:

```
m2[, ncol(m2) - 1] / m2[, ncol(m2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tail`

```
m2[tail(names(m2), 2)[1]]/m2[tail(names(m2), 1)]
```